# SSIS data load from sharepoint to SQL Server behaves different with different versions of Visual studio

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sharepoint-list

We have a SSIS package which loads data from sharepoint to SQL Server, we use the sharepointlist adaters for the same. We are facing an weird issue, the issue is:

When we run the package using  SSDT for Visual Studio 2012 it loads all the records from sharepoint to SQL Server table (549 records), but when we run the same package using SSDT 2015 or 2017 it loads only few of the records (281 out of 549 records) but there are no error messages in the package execution.

Note: We are running it in SQL Server 2016

Did anyone face a similar issue? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: SSIS packaged are *developed* in Visual Studio, they aren't run there. 2012 is too old too. Projects written with it can't be opened in newer Visual Studio versions just like that, they have to be converted. Finally, SSIS packages are developed using SSDT, which is now [a separate download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017). Visual Studio 2017 isn't enough

Comment: To test what's wrong, first make sure there aren't any "ignore" error rules. Second, use Fiddler or a similar debugging proxy to see what HTTP requests are made to the SharePoint server and what is returned. Are the requests different? That would mean something changed in the connector configuration. Are the *responses* different, even though the requests are the same? It means the change happened on the SharePoint side, not SSIS

Comment: "*they aren't run there."* @PanagiotisKanavos ? You *can* run Packages in SSDT. Certainly during development you'll be running it to test it and ensure behaviour is correct; deploying the entire project for every change to a single package would be a very foolish idea. I suspect you mean that for final live Deployment that packages should be run from SQL Server, not SSDT, but that doesn't translate well from your comment.

Comment: @Larnu how do you deploy a single package to the SSISDB when using the project deployment model? Unless something has changed in recent VS versions, I am fairly certain that the entire project must be deployed.

Comment: You can't @JacobH, I didn't say you could. What I was saying is that during development of a package you aren't going to deploy every single iteration of a package (project) to your development server, when the entire package is incomplete. You'd debug the package in SSDT by running it. It was suggested, before my comment, that you can't run packages in SSDT, where as that isn't true; I do it on an almost daily basis.

Comment: Actually, @JacobH I may be wrong, you might well be able to deploy a single package. From a Google, looks like the feature was added with SQl Server 2016.

Comment: We can deploy single package to SSISDB, I have done it in SQL 2016, it is fairly simple.

Comment: Update: I have tried to pull data using Odata source and it also is not extracting full set of data.